# TypeCasting using Generic Data Types (Java)

Tags: java, integer, wrapper

```
public class Main
{
    static <T extends Number , E > void add ( T o2 )
    {
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       E e2 = (E) o2; // it must be casted to integer

       System.out.println( e2.getClass().getName() ); // java.lang.Float ( it is not 
       casted )
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Main g1= new Main();
       g1.<Float , Integer>add( 6.2f );

   }
}
```

What I'm trying to implement is similar to what the below code evaluates to -

```
       float y = 6.2f;
       int x = (int) y;
       System.out.println(x);
```

I need to convert Float to Integer in the function add. The System.out statement should print java.lang.Integer as output.
How can i solve this? Is it possible to implement this or i need to workaround this code. Please Help.

Comment: Why do you need generics for this?

Comment: The `(int)y` is a language level conversion, not a typesystem-level conversion, so you can't use `Class` or generics to make it happen.

Comment: No the part float y = 6.2f and converting y to x is just to showcase what i'm trying to achieve by the add function. The comment in the main function separates both parts. Both are separate things.